# Not showing data from localStorage

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rich-text-editor

I am using ReactJs for my project, and I'm using a rich text editor, when I write something in the content aria then I'm able to save data inside localStorage, but when I want to have data inside content body after refresh the whole page, It doesn't show data in the content aria but I have saved data succesfully in the localStorage

I don't know where is problem,

I have tried by this way:

```
  const blogFromLS = () => {
    if (typeof window === "undefined") {
      return false;
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem("blog")) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("blog"));
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

```
  const [body, setBody] = useState({
    editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
    blogFromLS: blogFromLS(),
  });

  const { editorState } = body;

  const onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    setBody({ editorState });
    formData.set(
      "body",
      draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))
    );
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      localStorage.setItem(
        "blog",
        JSON.stringify(
          draftToHtml(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))
        )
      );
    }
  };
```

```
  <div className="form-group">
          <Editor
            className="editorCustom"
            editorState={editorState}
            wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
            editorClassName="demo-editor"
            onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
            placeholder="write something..."
            // onChange={handleBody}
            // value={body}
          />
        </div>
```

Any Suggestion please.

Comment: Can you cross-check whether the blog key is stored in local storage by going to the application tab of the google-dev tool?

Comment: Yes, I have checked Application tab, when I write something in the content aria then It has been saved, when I refresh my page then still saved data in the localStorage but not show in my content aria what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close to aim what you want to achieve.
What you have to tweak is the way how you initialize the editor's state. You have to pass the state which you store in localStorage during the initialization editor component. To do so you have to use `EditorState.createWithContent` static method.

```
const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState({
editorState: blogFromLS()
  ? EditorState.createWithContent(blogFromLS())
  : EditorState.createEmpty()
});
```

Also it seems that you don't need to use `draftToHtml`, because we need to save a raw content state and not an html or whatever.

Here is the complete solution:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Editor, EditorState, convertToRaw, convertFromRaw } from "draft-js";
import "draft-js/dist/Draft.css";
import { useState } from "react";

const blogFromLS = () => {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    return false;
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem("blog")) {
    return convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("blog")));
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState({
    editorState: blogFromLS()
      ? EditorState.createWithContent(blogFromLS())
      : EditorState.createEmpty()
  });
  const onChange = (editorState) => {
    setEditorState({ editorState });
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      localStorage.setItem(
        "blog",
        JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))
      );
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Editor editorState={editorState.editorState} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The code snippet is also available here in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-river-yg4ix?file=/src/App.js:0-988).

Comment: Thanks, but I got another error, `TypeError: editorState.getCurrentContent is not a function`

Comment: Try to double-check what `editorState` variable is referring to. It should be an instance of `EditorState`.
To do so just wrap your `editorState` variable into console.log somewhere above where you call `editorState.getCurrentContent` and check the output in the console, if it referring to something another fix it or use the right variable where you store EditorState. In your code snippet in the post above, you store it in `body.editorState`.